# Getting 2032 error (On only 1 machine)

Tags: apache-flex, air

I built an AIR app a while ago. One of the users today got a new machine (XP) and keeps getting a 2032 error when the app tries to send/receive data via `HTTPService` I verified that this page works when accessed within a web browser. It also works on AIR apps on other machines. The page and the AIR app haven't been changed for months, the only thing that has changed is this particular users computer. I recompiled to get a more specific error and this is what I got:

```
(mx.messaging.messages::ErrorMessage)#0
  body = ""
  clientId = "DirectHTTPChannel0"
  correlationId = "B38588EC-AEA0-84F0-F5B2-F6B6AB6C3456"
  destination = ""
  extendedData = (null)
  faultCode = "Server.Error.Request"
  faultDetail = "Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032" errorID=2032]. URL: https://www.example.com/mypage.php"
  faultString = "HTTP request error"
  headers = (Object)#1
    DSStatusCode = 0
  messageId = "2BC38D14-63DD-345E-50DD-F6B6AEE75438"
  rootCause = (flash.events::IOErrorEvent)#2
    bubbles = false
    cancelable = false
    currentTarget = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
      bytesLoaded = 0
      bytesTotal = 0
      data = ""
      dataFormat = "text"
    errorID = 2032
    eventPhase = 2
    target = (flash.net::URLLoader)#3
    text = "Error #2032"
    type = "ioError"
  timestamp = 0
  timeToLive = 0
```

As I am writing this I had the user restart and relaunch the application, it is now working so I am not too worried about it, but I am still curious what could have happened if anyone has any ideas?

### Update

Today (next day) It is happening again and restart isn't even fixing it today. It has to be something on her machine interfering causing the problem because I can run the program on any other machine just fine with no problem. Not sure what it could be or how to troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 0):

Did the server hiccup just then, i.e. downtime and/or cosmic ray? Cross reference the user access time with the apache access/error.log on the server. Did `crossdomain.xml` change anyplace that your program references?

Comment: Actually I am pretty sure something on this users computer was causing the issue (e.g. like a firewall but I checked that). Because I could do it simultaneously on another machine and it worked evey time on every other machine and never on the one in question (until I restarted it and now it is working fine.)

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat the same problem here but with a Flash (Web - Flex 4.1 SDK) application. 
after trying out a huge assortment of solutions we narrowed we finally came up with one that works pretty reliably for all systems, including newly installed machines.

**A**. add global event listeners at the root (or stage) of the application, on flex preinitialize stage.

```
IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR
IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR
HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS
ErrorEvent.ERROR
SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR
```

if an error is cought - `event.preventDefault();`

**B**. add event listeners on every loader used in the App for the following errors:

```
IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR
SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR
HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS
```

*to attempt recovery, like falling back to an external interface call...

**C**. place all the SWZ files from the bin-release folder together with the SWF file in the same path on the server you use to deliver your App. 
in my case these are the files needed:

```
sparkskins_4.5.1.21328.swz
spark_4.5.1.21328.swz
textLayout_2.0.0.232.swz
rpc_4.5.1.21328.swz
osmf_1.0.0.16316.swz
framework_4.5.1.21328.swz
```

* to discover this i used Chrome developer console to see which errors occur on the page and discovered a chain of 404s when the app tries to download these files.

**D**. have a properly configured crossdomain.xml policy file which includes the allow http request xml tag.

```
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
```

replace the * as needed in your particular case.

Cheers